# ¿Cómo filtrar varios datos al tiempo y que queden por separado? y "problemas con tíldes y ñ"

Tags: r

¡Hola!

Quisiera saber si es posible filtrar varios datos pero que queden en dataframes diferentes, ya que hasta ahora lo he hecho por separado, pero me toma mucho tiempo, y quisiera saber si es posible optimizar el tiempo para realizar esta acción.

Es decir, tengo una columna llamada "Sites" con 176 sitios diferentes,y quiero dejar cada sitio por separado, por ahora he usado la función "filter" del paquete "dplyr" con cada sitio por aparte.

Por otro lado, al intentar filtrar algunos sitios, estos aparecen con tildes y ñ, y R no me los reconoce, ¿cómo podría hacer que R los reconociera?

Aquí un ejemplo de esos sitios

```
 [32] "13 Cajic\xe1-Manas"   
 [34] "15 Bogot\xe1 - Mochuelo"   
 [48] "Campa\xf1a Andes 2010"                                                                    
 [49] "Campa\xf1a Caldas 2010"                                                                   
 [50] "Campa\xf1a Caracoli 2009"                                                                 
 [51] "Campa\xf1a Caramanta 2009"                                                                
 [52] "Campa\xf1a Caucasia 2009"                                                                 
 [53] "Campa\xf1a Cisneros 2008"                                                                 
 [54] "Campa\xf1a Ciudad Bolivar 2010"                                                           
 [55] "Campa\xf1a Ebejico 2009"                                                                  
 [56] "Campa\xf1a Entrerrios 2008"                                                               
 [57] "Campa\xf1a Gomez Plata 2009"                                                              
 [58] "Campa\xf1a Itagui 2009"                                                                   
 [59] "Campa\xf1a Jerico 2008"                                                                   
 [60] "Campa\xf1a La Estrella 2010"                                                              
 [61] "Campa\xf1a La Pintada 2010"                                                               
 [62] "Campa\xf1a Maceo 2009"                                                                    
 [63] "Campa\xf1a Puerto Berrio 2009"
 [92] "Estaci\xf3n Altavista-Medell\xedn"                                                        
 [93] "Estaci\xf3n Envigado-Fundadores"                                                          
 [94] "Estaci\xf3n Liceo Isabel" 
 [125] "Instituci\xf3n Educativa Col. - Girardota"
```

¡Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes de cuidar leer con un encoding correcto tu `data.frame` , checa la documentación de la función `read.csv`, el parametro `encoding`

Puedes hacerlo con la función `split`

```
?split 

data <- read.csv('path_de_archivo', encoding = 'UTF-8') # esto arregla lo de las 'ñ' 
                                        # o bien prueba con el valor  "encoding='latin'"
```

Esto puede tener dependencia con la configuración de R que estas usando y tu sistema operativo

```
# simulamos tu data.frame
data <-  iris[ sample(1:dim(iris)[1], size = dim(iris)[1]*5, replace = TRUE), ] # un dataset dummie 
data <- as.data.frame(data)
niveles <- c("13 Cajicá-Manas", "15 Bogotá - Mochuelo", "Campaña Andes 2010", "Campaña Caldas 2010", "Campaña Caracoli 2009")
data$Sites <- sample(  x = niveles, size = dim(data)[1], replace = TRUE) # aumentamos tu columna por la que quieres separar

conjuntos.data.frames <- split( x = data, f = data$Sites)     # LA MAGIA
```

Ahora tienes una lista de data.frames y puedes acceder a ellos con el nombre del nivel que buscas

```
names(conjuntos.data.frames)[1]
[1] "13 Cajicá-Manas"

head(conjuntos.data.frames[["13 Cajicá-Manas"]])
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
145           6.7         3.3          5.7
42.1          4.5         2.3          1.3
59            6.6         2.9          4.6
26            5.0         3.0          1.6
138           6.4         3.1          5.5
29            5.2         3.4          1.4
Petal.Width    Species           Sites
145          2.5  virginica 13 Cajicá-Manas
42.1         0.3     setosa 13 Cajicá-Manas
59           1.3 versicolor 13 Cajicá-Manas
26           0.2     setosa 13 Cajicá-Manas
138          1.8  virginica 13 Cajicá-Manas
29           0.2     setosa 13 Cajicá-Manas
```

- Update si quieres guardar cada `data.frame` puedes partir del código anterior y la mejor práctica en R es usar programación funcional:

```
lapply(X=conjuntos.data.frames, FUN= function(x){
    write.csv(x, file = paste0(as.character(x$Sites[1]), '.csv'), row.names = FALSE)
})
```